# Strange Behaviour : unlink not deleting files in php

Tags: php

Somehow unlink is not deleting the file. If you see in the file, am copying from $incoming_file_path to $processing_file_path and than after copying is done. I am trying to delete the file in $incoming_file_path but somehow is it not deleting and I really wonder why it is happening so. Kindly advice.

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting',0);
$file = fopen("pid.txt","w+") or die('!fopen');
flock($file, LOCK_EX);

//Folder where xml files will be coming in from UPC
$incoming_file_path = "/home/xmlcontainer";
$processing_file_path = "/home/process_file";
$threshold = time() - 30;
foreach( glob($incoming_file_path.'/*')as $key => $value ) {
  if ( filemtime($value) <= $threshold ) {
    copy($incoming_file_path.$value,$processing_file_path.$value);
    print_r($incoming_file_path.$value."\n");
    unlink($incoming_file_path.$value);
    print_r($incoming_file_path.$value."\n");
    print_r($processing_file_path.$value."\n");
    }
}
flock($file,LOCK_UN);

?>
```

---

Comment: I am getting `error` as `unexpected T_STRING` at `$incoming_files _LM = date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime("$incoming_files"))."\n";`, not sure why it gives me such an error. I have checked for common cause but didn't find any. Guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: last time i looked, variables couldn't contain spaces in their names ($incoming_files _LM = ...)

Comment: I have rectified that error but now am getting multiple warning like `filemtime(): stat failed for TestInput.xml` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` but code is not running as it should.

Comment: TestInput.xml is one of the XML file which is present in xmlcontainer folder.

Comment: `$incoming_files` is not an array, so it can't be used with `foreach` - see the docs on `readdir`: http://us.php.net/readdir

Comment: I tried using `$incoming_files = array(readdir($incoming_file_handle))` but still it is giving me errors. Actually this is my first time using php and so what could be possible work around for this issue

Comment: I think `scandir` would solve the issue as compared to using `readdir`

Comment: I tried using scandir but it is going into infinite loop printing warning messages  `scandir() expects parameter 1 to be string` and `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readdir() returns the filename without the path. So, in your script instead of `filemtime(/home/xmlcontainer/TestInput.xml)` only `filemtime(TestInput.xml)` is executed.

Also $incoming_files contains a single file name (as string) within your while-loop. The nested `foreach($incoming_files as ...)`will never work.

btw: why do you format the timestamp via date() and then compare the resulting strings against each other?

```
$file = fopen("pid.txt","w+") or die('!fopen');
flock($file, LOCK_EX);

//Folder where xml files will be coming in from UPC
$incoming_file_path = "/home/xmlcontainer";
$processing_file_path = "/home/process_file";
$threshold = time() - 30;

foreach( glob($incoming_file_path.'/*') as $source ) {
  if ( filemtime($source) <= $threshold ) {
    // copy / move
    // process
    // unlink
  }
}
flock($file,LOCK_UN);
```

Comment: I want to check last modified time of each file present in xmlcontainer folder and if it is less than current time - 30 secs than I assume that it is fully transferred and than I transfer that file to another folder and rm it from xmlcontainer folder. Then I invoke .php script with that file as input.